# google maps - modify infowindow css on or after click event

Tags: google-maps, events, infowindow

On a Google Map, I would like to adjust initial layout of InfoWindow before Infowindow is displayed. Specifically I would like to do this on or just after click eventL

```
            // on click             
            $(".tabs").hide();
            $("#summary").show();
```

This is the code that (successfully) creates the infowindow when marker is clicked.  I need to find where to add above code and event to put it on.

```
        // Renders the marker on the specified map
        marker.setMap(map); 

        // create an InfoWindow
        var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();         

        // add content to your InfoWindow
        infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + infoWindowContent);

        // add listener on InfoWindow - close last infoWindow  before opening new one 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            //Close active window if exists 
            if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

            // Open InfoWindow
            infoWnd.open(map, marker);

            // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
            activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;

            ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Putting a listener on the InfoWindow on 'domready' event. When this triggers, then apply your changes to content of InfoWindow.

```
        // Renders the marker on the specified map
        marker.setMap(map); 

        // create an InfoWindow
        var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();         

        // put a listener of InfoWindow, when "domready", make changes to content
        google.maps.event.addListener(infoWnd, 'domready', function() {
            $("span.tabs").hide();
            $("#summary_tab").show();                       
        });

        // add content to your InfoWindow
        infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + infoWindowContent + "<div>");


        // add listener on InfoWindow for CLICK event- close last infoWindow  before opening new one 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


            //Close active window if exists
            if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

            // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
            activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;

            // Open InfoWindow
            infoWnd.open(map, marker);              
        });
```